# pandas dataframe comparing previous rows with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python and Pandas newbie here. I have the following dataframe and I would like to be able compare rows where the route and vals are the same in the previous row/rows and update the frm and to accordingly.

```
DF:
   route  frm    to  val
0      1    0   100    3
1      1  100   300    2
2      1  300   500    3
3      1  500  9999    3
4      2    0   100    3
5      2  100   300    3
6      2  300   500    3
7      2  500  9999    3
```

```
Desired Output:
   route  frm    to  val
0      1    0   100    3
1      1  100   300    2
3      1  300  9999    3
7      2  0    9999    3
```

I have tried the following using `shift()` which gets me some part of the way, but I am not sure the best way on how to achieve the desired output.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
df['f'] = np.where((df.route.eq(df.route.shift())) & (df.val == df.val.shift()),df.frm.shift(),df.frm)
df['t'] = np.where((df.route.eq(df.route.shift())) & (df.val == df.val.shift()),df.to.shift(),df.to)
```

```
Output:

   route  frm    to  val    f    t
0      1    0   100    3    0  100
1      1  100   300    2  100  300
2      1  300   500    3  300  500
3      1  500  9999    3  300  500
4      2    0   100    3    0  100
5      2  100   300    3    0  100
6      2  300   500    3  100  300
7      2  500  9999    3  300  500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom `groupby.agg`:

```
(df.groupby(['route', df['val'].ne(df['val'].shift()).cumsum()],
            as_index=False)
   .agg({'route': 'first',
         'frm': 'first',
         'to': 'last',
         'val': 'last'})
 )
```

Output:

```
   route  frm    to  val
0      1    0   100    3
1      1  100   300    2
2      1  300  9999    3
3      2    0  9999    3
```

Comment: thanks! that seems to work great. I understand the groupby, but a little less clear on what / how cumsum and the agg are being used here...if you have a chance to explain.

Comment: The successive difference + cumsum is a classical grouping trick (to group successive values). Try to run `df['val'].ne(df['val'].shift()).cumsum()`. The `agg` defines an aggregation per group, here 'first' for all columns except 'to' fire which we want the 'last', note that you cutie use `min`/`max`. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I just realized my comment was full of typos... Damn autocorrect... "fire" -> "for", "cutie" -> "can"

Comment: no worries :) luckly, I was able to decrypt those.